# Issue with Date.now() method creating same value for different inputs

Tags: javascript, lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

I am trying to copy bunch of contacts at a time from the table. I am facing small issue with copying contacts.When I am doing this I am getting same Id for new contacts created and causing issue when doing this action.This is happening if I do this second time continuously without updating the table.

Suppose for example there are 10 contacts and I selected first 3 contacts and clicked on copy contact.Now the Ids of the newly created contacts are lets say ABC-1508217223882, ABC-1508217223983 , ABC-1508217223994.Now again I am selecting the newly created contacts and clicking on copy is creating same Ids which is copying wrong contacts.

I think there is an issue with Date.now() method when the contactListSO.Id is created.Because we are using the contactLineId to get the ContactLineRecord.

Can anyone let me know what to do to resolve this issue? Appreciate your help in advance!!

```
**//CONTROLLER//**    
copyContacts: function(component, contactLineIds){
        var contactListSO;
        var contactList = component.get('v.contactList');
        var newContactsToCreate = component.get('v.copiedContacts');

        for(var i=0; i<contactLineIds.length; i++){

          contactListSO = helper.getContactLineRecord(component,contactList, contactLineIds[i]);
        }

          contactListSO = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(contactListSO));
          contactListSO.Id = 'ABC-' + Date.now();
          contactList.push(contactListSO);
          newContactsToCreate.push(contactListSO);

        }

          helper.setContactList(component, 'v.contactList', contactList);
          helper.setContactList(component, 'v.copiedContacts', newContactsToCreate);
        },

**//HELPER//**
  getContactLineRecord: function (component, contactList, contactLineId) {
    if (contactList.length > 0) {
      for (var i=0 ; i < contactList.length; i += 1) {
        if (contactLineId === contactList[i].Id) {
          return contactList[i];
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  },


  setContactList: function (component, nameOfList, value) {
    component.set(nameOfList, value);
  },
```

Comment: Place `console.log(Date.now())` to check if that is really causing issue. When do you mean by saying 'without updating the table'? Is it about refresh or setting the list values?

Comment: I kept console.log and able to find the issue and resolve the issue. What i mean was setting list value.
contactListSO.Id = 'ABC-' + Date.now() + i; resolved the isssue

Comment: Possibly this is a fix  you used for now but that does not reveals the reason of why is the Date.Now() returning old timestamp. Also, include component code here.